# Error creating Lambda trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a very simple Lambda trigger: when a new file is dropped into a specific folder in my bucket I want my Lambda to run and process the file.

This works fine on a new test bucket I set up in the same region, but when I try to add the trigger to my main bucket I get this error: "There was an error creating the trigger: We encountered an internal error. Please try again."

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Try again. If that fails, you will need to contact AWS support.

Comment: Does your user have permission to do what you are asking the console to do?